# Heroku crashed: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"

Tags: django, git, heroku, boot

I'm deploying my Django project on Heroku but I kept getting this **Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command** error after typing `heroku open`.

#### crashed log

```
2019-02-08T05:11:47.595848+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=**.herokuapp.com request_id=754cd442-2b92-4d35-ab73-f6f3f4b47dd2 fwd="144.214.90.65" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-02-08T05:11:48.592697+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=**.herokuapp.com request_id=1dfcc7fa-e278-42be-b02a-0df04c824b57 fwd="144.214.90.65" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

#### `heroku logs --tail`

```
2019-02-08T04:25:27.848612+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user ***@gmail.com
2019-02-08T05:10:08.937759+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-02-08T05:21:19.195680+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-02-08T05:27:16.830898+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi --log-file -`
2019-02-08T05:27:19.380582+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-02-08T05:27:19.363391+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2019-02-08T05:27:19.253888+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-08 05:27:19 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-02-08T05:27:19.254420+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-08 05:27:19 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:4868 (4)
2019-02-08T05:27:19.254514+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-08 05:27:19 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-02-08T05:27:19.258397+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-08 05:27:19 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-02-08T05:27:19.262923+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-08 05:27:19 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-02-08T05:27:19.262927+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-02-08T05:27:19.262929+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-02-08T05:27:19.262931+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-02-08T05:27:19.262932+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-02-08T05:27:19.262934+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-02-08T05:27:19.262936+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-02-08T05:27:19.262937+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-02-08T05:27:19.262939+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-02-08T05:27:19.262941+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-02-08T05:27:19.262942+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-02-08T05:27:19.262944+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-02-08T05:27:19.262946+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-02-08T05:27:19.262947+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-02-08T05:27:19.262949+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-02-08T05:27:19.262950+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-02-08T05:27:19.262952+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gettingstarted'
2019-02-08T05:27:19.263083+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-08 05:27:19 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-02-08T05:27:19.287592+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-08 05:27:19 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-02-08T05:27:19.287748+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-08 05:27:19 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

#### My `Procfile`

`web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi --log-file -`

#### `settings.py`

```
"""
***
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '**',  # subdoamin wildcard
    'localhost',
    '127.0.0.1',
    '144.214.90.65' 
]

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # 'product.apps.ProductConfig',
    'product',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

***

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR + '/templates/'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = '***.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'CET'  # UTC + 1
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

# The URL to use when referring to static files (where they will be served from)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# The absolute path to the directory where collectstatic will collect static files for deployment.
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# check new places here so I


CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER = False
HOST_SCHEME = "http://"
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 60
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True

SECURE_FRAME_DENY = False
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 2019-02-08T05:27:19.262952+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gettingstarted'

You've forgotten to add, commit and push `gettingstarted` directory. It's required by your `Procfile`.